# How to pass an image from one fragment to another using Safe Args?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, pass-data, android-safe-args

I want to pass some data from one fragment to another and I have managed to successfully pass every single data except an imageView, I don't know how to do that. Here's my code below passing data:

**1st fragment:**

```
val action: NavDirections =
            PartnersFragmentDirections.actionPartnersFragmentToPartnerItemFragment(
                obj.name,
                obj.short_description,
                obj.connection_state,
                obj.logo_path,
                obj.id
            )
        findNavController().navigate(action)
```

**2nd fragment**

```
 if (arguments != null) {
            val arg = PartnerItemFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
            binding.partnerName.text = arg.name
            binding.partnerDescription.text = arg.shortDescription
            connectionState = arg.connectionState.toString()
            id = arg.id.toString()
```

Comment: pass the image URI instead ?

Comment: But how? Am I supposed to use Glide?

Comment: You cannot pass an `ImageView` between fragments. Where is the image in the `ImageView` coming from?

Comment: It comes as a string from the API, as you can see in the first fragment I declare it as an argument from navigation_graph

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution about this using Glide.

```
if (arguments != null) {
            val arg = PartnerFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
            binding.partnerName.text = arg.name
            binding.partnerDescription.text = arg.shortDescription
            connectionState = arg.connectionState.toString()
            val logoPath = arg.logoPath
            Glide
                .with(binding.partnerLogo.context)
                .load(logoPath)
               .into(binding.partnerLogo)
            id = arg.id.toString()
       }
```